# Complicated array formula - lookup with multiple criteria including date range

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

[Jobs Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONhKH.png)  [Rates Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoRdj.png)

I use this Google Sheet to track proofreading jobs. I'm trying to change columns filled with formulas to array formulas in the header row 1 so that they automatically apply to new entries without me having to fill them down.

I have this complicated formula to calculate the Total in Jobs!P:

```
=if(O2>vlookup(E2,Discounts!A:B,2,0),O2-vlookup(E2,Discounts!A:B,2,0),0)*
(index(Rates!$C$2:$C$30,match(B2&C2,Rates!$A$2:$A$30&Rates!$B$2:$B$30,0))+
vlookup(D2,Upcharges!A:B,2,0))*vlookup(E2,Discounts!A:C,3,0)
```

My issue is with that second line. Right now it references the Turnaround and Category (Jobs!B:C) to return the Rate (Rates!C), but I need it to also find the rate where the Date In (Jobs!F) is between the Start Date and End Date (Rates!D:E).

I tried using SUMIFS to pull the rate, but it just returned 0 for the entire column:

```
={"Total"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(O2:O),"",
 IF(O2:O>VLOOKUP(E2:E, Discounts!A:B, 2, 0), 
    O2:O-VLOOKUP(E2:E, Discounts!A:B, 2, 0), 0)*
 (SUMIFS(Rates!C2:C,Rates!A2:A,B2:B,Rates!B2:B,C2:C,
Rates!D2:D,">="&F2:F,Rates!E2:E,"<="&F2:F)+
  VLOOKUP(D2:D, Upcharges!A:B, 2, 0))*VLOOKUP(E2:E, Discounts!A:C, 3, 0)))}
```

A sandbox version of the Google Sheet is available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U3MAKHDPwQ3zL7gz0PahcBXN5XTpWoVVbshVC-7HkY4/edit?usp=sharing). I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

try in P1:

```
={"Total"; ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(O2:O>VLOOKUP(E2:E, Discounts!A:B, 2, 0), 
    O2:O-VLOOKUP(E2:E, Discounts!A:B, 2, 0), 0)*
 (VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C, {Rates!A2:A30&Rates!B2:B30, Rates!C2:C30}, 2, 0)+
  VLOOKUP(D2:D, Upcharges!A:B, 2, 0))*VLOOKUP(E2:E, Discounts!A:C, 3, 0))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for responding. That does work for what I have currently but does not account for rate changes. Right now if I were to change my rates, I would simply copy the existing totals and paste values and then proceed using the formula for new jobs added at the bottom, but that won't work if there's only one formula in the header row. I need it to use the date the job was received and look up the rate where that date is between the start date and end date on the rates sheet.

Comment: which date from Jobs sheet coresponds to date range in Reates sheet?

Comment: Date In (Column F)